# a dynamic sorted navigation with Jekyll, Gulp and Markdown

Tags: gulp, metadata, markdown, jekyll

I try to do an navigation which uses Metadata from my Markdown-Files.
So my problem is that I only use jekyll for the site and gulp for markdown and the problem is that I don´t know how I get gulp taken the Metadata and put it into to jekyll navigation.

my default page for my navigation looking like this:

```
<nav id="subNav">
    {% assign pages = site.pages | sort:"weight"  %}
    <ul class="secondLevel">
        {% for p in pages %}
        <li>
            <a {% if p.url == page.url %}class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ p.path }}">
                {{ p.title }}
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and my Gulpfile for Markdown looking like this:

```
gulp.task('markdown', function() {
return gulp.src('src/fileadmin/layout/compass/scss/media_all/*.md')
.pipe(markdown({
    gfm: true, 
    tables: true,
    breaks: true, 
    pedantic: true, 
    sanitize: false, 
    smartLists: true,
    smartypants: true 
}))

.pipe(insert.transform(function(content,file){
        var ext = path.extname(file.path),
            base = path.basename(file.path, ext); // https://nodejs.org/api/util.html | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612192/get-file-basename-in-gulp-replacer-task
        var comment = '---\nlayout: default\ntitle: ' + base.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + base.substr(1) + '\n---\n\n';// http://phpjs.org/functions/ucfirst/ | http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp
        return comment + content;
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(destDir));
```

});

So the part of the gulpfile was used for an non dynamic navigation.
How can I get a dynamic Navigation out of my Markdown-Metadata?
I hope someone could understand whats my problem and can help...

Comment: Could you provide your sample markdown file?

Answer (score 0):

Since your md files contains metadata (assuming at the top of file), you need to using [gulp-meta-markdown](https://github.com/andorx/gulp-meta-markdown) instead of [gulp-markdown](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-markdown) to render them.

I already forked [gulp-markdown](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-markdown) to another version that supported metadata markdown here [gulp-meta-markdown](https://github.com/andorx/gulp-meta-markdown). It supports the following format of markdown:

```md
---
title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
---
# Heading
```

Replace `markdown` with this module by following:

```js
var metaMarkdown = require('gulp-meta-markdown');
var data = require('gulp-data');
...
return gulp.src('src/fileadmin/layout/compass/scss/media_all/*.md')
    .pipe(metaMarkdown({
        gfm: true, 
        tables: true,
        breaks: true, 
        pedantic: true, 
        sanitize: false, 
        smartLists: true,
        smartypants: true 
    }))
```

By this, you will receive stringified string of object through `file.contents` property.

```
{
    meta: {
        title: "Lorem ipsum dolor..."
    },
    html: <rendered html code>
}
```

In order to get this object, you need to do a parsing (you still can use `gulp-insert`)

```
.pipe(data(function(file) {
    var fileObj = JSON.parse(content);

    // do whatever you want with 
    // fileObj.meta
    // fileObj.html

    file.contents = new Buffer(fileContents.html.toString());
}))
```

From this point, you can place navigation to metadata section and use it for rendering.